# unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)

Tags: laravel, smtp

I am using SMTP server to send mails from Laravel app, using these configs:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=****@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

2-step verification is enabled on Gmail account

it works fine when I try to send mails from my local, but when deploying to App engine, it throws an error

```
"Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)"
```

I have tried to change port -->

```
MAIL_PORT=587
```

but didn't work, and tried

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

but also didn't work,

I tried to change the driver -->

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
```

but throws a new error -->

```
Expected response code 220 but got an empty response
```

what other changes should I consider? and why does it work from my local but not on App Engine?